# A word or phrase that defines "Preconceived opinions based on experience or reason?"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

If **Prejudice** is defined as Preconceived opinion **not** based on reason or experience. 
then what, if any, is the word that defines "Preconceived opinions that are based on experience or reason?"

Comment: That's not the only definition of _Prejudice_; it doesn't have to be wrong, just previously decided. One can be prejudiced in favor of the truth, for instance. If you simply mean things that are taken for granted and can't be contradicted -- especially in sentences and by word usage -- the word you want is [_Presupposition_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Presuppositiontriggers.pdf).

Comment: In general, whatever *you* think is either "fact", or "opinion based on experience or reason". If anyone else thinks differently, that's "prejudice".

Comment: Informed opinion.

Answer (score 3):

**Anecdotal**: Evidence or beliefs based on what has happened to someone personally.
(definition typically says in the form of stories that people tell - but the main point is the notion is not based on any empirical or scientific evidence).

*"His conclusions are not supported by data; they are based only on **anecdotal** evidence."*

Answer (score 1):

An *opinion* is a conclusion reached that is not factually determined. [Oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/opinion?q=opinion) offers these two definitions

> a view or judgement formed about something, not necessarily based on fact or knowledge:
>   *that, in my opinion, is right*
>
> a statement of advice by an expert on a professional matter:
>   *if in doubt, get a second opinion*

In both cases, the result of the analysis is not an exact calculus of indisputable facts, but requires some measure of decision-making by the opinion holder.

Obviously, there is a wide spectrum in the quantity and quality of information that leads to the opinion, ranging from none to a wealth of data and experience by an expert in the field.

The definition of *[preconceived](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/preconceived?q=preconceived)* is

> (of an idea or opinion) formed before having the evidence for its truth or usefulness:
>   *the same set of facts can be tailored to fit any preconceived belief*

The phrase *preconceived opinions that are based on experience or reason* seems somewhat oxymoronic. If it is *preconceived*, the suggestion is that it lacks evidence (experience being a form of evidence and reason the analysis of that evidence).

If facts are indisputable, the conclusion is not an opinion. If there is some room for differing opinions, it's because all the facts are not, or cannot be known, and some prejudgment (before all facts are know) is necessary.

It seems as if you are describing a circumstance where some facts are known and the opinion holder has experience and reason on her side. Rather than describing it as *preconceived*, you may want

> *informed opinion*
>
> or
>
> *educated guess*

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following two:

***stereotyping*** and 
***pigeonholing***

Both these terms imply a certain cognitive component

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to [bias](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bias).

> 3a : bent, tendency
>   b : an inclination of temperament or outlook;

although this definition refers also to "prejudice."

Answer (score 0):

A single word for a preconceived opinion that *could* be based on reason or experience is *prejudgment*. However, there is no single word for prejudgment based on reason or experience. The two-word phrase *experiential prejudice* is problematic because although literally, the word *prejudice* derives from *prejudgment*, the words do not mean the same thing: modern dictionary definitions of *prejudice* require that the opinion *not* be based on experience or reason.

Answer (score 0):

If in debates, I would use `bigotry` for a preconceived opinions. Again, it all depends on the context of the subject and the mood of the audience.

Answer (score 0):

If one has lived long enough, opinions can resemble hunches.  The evidence I've read indicates that these hunches are the result of subconscious recollection of varied past experiences, filtered by the brain to give direction in times of conscious uncertainty.

Those who have religion in their life believe these hunches to be signals from a deity.